# Compare two values of two "lists" against each other and count instances where values match

Tags: sml

To start, let me share that I'm a complete novice at formal programming and have decided to start learning after many years of working in IT from the administrative side.  So I am starting from scratch and hopefully unlearning any bad habits I've picked up over the years.

To help myself out, I've started a course online that has some homework.  I've promised myself to not cheat, but I'm struggling on this problem and would like some help.  I did see a similar post that was answered, but the answer doesn't make sense to me, so I'm asking again.

Here is the assignment ...

> " Write a function "number_in_months" that takes a list of dates and a list of months (i.e., an int list) and returns the number of dates in the list of dates that are in any of the months in the list of months. Assume the list of months has no number repeated. Hint: Use your answer to the previous problem. "

You'll notice that it refers to the previous problem. I've shared it below.

> " Write a function "number_in_month" that takes a list of dates and a month (i.e., an int) and returns how many dates in the list are in the given month. "

I was able to solve the previous problem with this code.

```
fun number_in_month (dates : (int * int * int) list , month : int ) =
  if null dates
  then 0
  else 
    if ( #2 (hd dates) = month )
    then 1 + number_in_month (tl dates , month)
    else number_in_month (tl dates , month)
```

In my REPL `val test2 = number_in_month ([(2012,2,28),(2013,12,1)],2) = 1` tests true

So I've re-read the material and re-watched the videos a few times and still haven't gotten to an understanding on how to solve the problem.  I can get it all to type check correctly but then get an `uncaught exception EMPTY`

I can recurse the "dates" list against the hd of the "months" list with no problem but to move on to the next value in the "months" list is killing me. So far I have tried many ways, but I'm stumped, and I'm feeling not just a little stupid. ;-)

```
fun number_in_months (dates : (int * int * int) list , months : int list ) =
  if null dates
  then 0
  else    
    if (#2 (hd dates) = (hd months)) 
    then 1 + number_in_months ( tl dates , months ) 
    else
      ????
```

It may be that I solved the first problem in such a way that it is throwing me off with the second.  I'm open to any ideas, guidance, or clues.  All will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the portion of your question related to the problem is pretty good, you've also provided a lot of commentary regarding your background and learning goals, none of which is relevant here. If you want to share that sort of information, you can do so in your user profile. Please refrain from doing so in your questions or answers - SO is strictly a technical site, not a forum or social networking site. You can find more information by taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages. Doing so will greatly improve your experiences here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Ken.  Ironically I just read that section from the welcome email this morning after my post.  I can be specific in the future.  Cheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more idiomatic way to handle empty lists and accessing elements of tuples in SML is pattern matching. If we consider your `number_in_month` function, we'd look at something like the following. If the list of dates is empty, it doesn't matter what month we're looking for, so we represent it with `_`.

Otherwise we consider the first tuple (but we only need to bind a name to the second element representing the month) and bind a name to the tail of the list. We count the tail of the list, and then if the current one is a match, add `1`.

```
fun number_in_month([], _) = 0
  | number_in_month(((_, mon, _)::other_dates), month) =
    let 
      val count_remaining = number_in_month(other_dates, month)
    in
      (if mon = month then 1 else 0) + count_remaining
    end;
```

For your `numbers_in_months` it seems you want to map over the list of months. `List.map` provides exactly this, and can directly use your prior work.

```
fun numbers_in_months(dates, months) =
  List.map (fn m => number_in_month(dates, m)) months;
```

```
numbers_in_months([(2012, 2, 28), (2013, 12, 1)], [4, 12, 2]);
```

Returns:

```
[0, 1, 1]
```

`map` can be implemented trivially, even without the niceties of pattern-matching.

```
fun map f lst =
  if null lst then []
  else f (hd lst) :: map f (tl lst)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I believe that this is probably the best way to go about getting the job done.  However, I believe I may have omitted the fact that we are able to use to use features that we have n't covered in class so far.  Your solution will also be checked for using only features discussed so far in class.  From the assignment - "In particular, you must not use SML's mutable references or arrays. Do not use pattern matching (until the next assignment where we will require it).

Comment: Can I ask that you try to solve it within the constraints mentioned above?   Either way you get the answer credit. Cheers